# twitter bootstrap custom carousel indicators

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, carousel, scaling

I want to change the carousel indicators with something like this:

[image: custom carousel indicators]

I have this markup for my carousel indicators:

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">


    <li data-target="#ShowCarousel-03" data-slide-to="0" class="active">
        <h4>IMAGE1</h4><br/><h5>subtitle</h5><br/><span>+</span>
    </li>


    <li data-target="#ShowCarousel-03" data-slide-to="0" class="active">
        <h4>IMAGE2</h4><br/><h5>subtitle</h5><br/><span>+</span>
    </li>
    <li data-target="#ShowCarousel-03" data-slide-to="2">
        <h4>IMAGE3</h4><br/><h5>subtitle</h5><br/><span>+</span>
    </li>
    <li data-target="#ShowCarousel-03" data-slide-to="0" class="active">
        <h4>IMAGE4</h4><br/><h5>subtitle</h5><br/><span>+</span>
    </li>

                    </ol>
```

CSS:

```
    .carousel-indicators {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0px;
     left: 0px;
     z-index: 5;
     margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
     }
      .carousel-indicators li{
    background: url(images/triangle.png) no-repeat;
    width:320px;
    height:176px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align:center;
}
```

When I resize my browser the carousel adapts to the width of the screen but the indicators are collapsing.

Can someone help me with a tip on how can I make this scale also on lower resolutions like the carousel images does?

Thank you!

L.E:

I've tried to put li elements like this:

```
 <div class="row-fluid">
 <div class="span3>
 <li data-target="#ShowCarousel-03" data-slide-to="0" class="active">
    <h4>IMAGE1</h4><br/><h5>subtitle</h5><br/><span>+</span>
  </li>
  <div class="span3>
 <li data-target="#ShowCarousel-03" data-slide-to="0" class="active">
    <h4>IMAGE1</h4><br/><h5>subtitle</h5><br/><span>+</span>
   </li>

  <div class="span3>
 <li data-target="#ShowCarousel-03" data-slide-to="0" class="active">
    <h4>IMAGE1</h4><br/><h5>subtitle</h5><br/><span>+</span>
 </li>
 </div>
 </div>
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use media query -

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
     .carousel-indicators li{
        background: url(images/triangle.png) no-repeat;
        background-size:120px 60px;
        width:120px;
        height:60px;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-align:center;
    }
```

Comment: I think this is not what I'm looking for because in this way I have to  have different images  for each screen size, it should be another method.

Comment: Use the same images, just resized with CSS as above. There could be other options but media queries is what I would suggest.

Comment: It's correct but in this way I still have to check for each resolution and see what size for image I should use in that particular resolution. Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

It's collapsing because the width of your carousel-indicator is 320px. You can't have fixed with if you also want your code to be responsive on mobile. You can substitute percentage rather than using a fixed width

```
.carousel-indicators li{
    background: url(images/triangle.png) no-repeat;
    max-width:25%;
    max-height:15%; /*or any other percentage that would look good*/
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Note that I used max-height and max-height so that I could keep the proportion of the image so it doesn't get stretched out in either direction.

Comment: This code worked well for me! I ended up needing to add !important to max-height and max-width for it to work. I also found out from this post that it is possible to add a custom image for the active indicator:

.carousel-indicators li.active{
background: url(../images/imagename.png) no-repeat !important;