# Customizing Twitter Bootstrap carousel pills

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

sorry if this is  a dumb question.

I'm attempting to use the Bootstrap Carousel, but would like to customize the carousel pills to use custome images, rather than their current form.

I'd like something similar to the [jquery Cycle pager.](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager2.html)

Is there a way to do this with the Carousel?
Is there a simple way to do this? or am i better off using jquery Cycle?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's a pull request relating to your question here: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/4222

I believe it's possible by editing the original Bootstrap CSS code below:

```
    carousel-pills span {
     display: inline-block;
     margin: 0px 5px;
     width: 10px;
     height: 10px;
     .border-radius(15px);
     background: @grayDark;
     @shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.25), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
     .box-shadow(@shadow);
     cursor: pointer;
     /* YOUR CSS HERE */
    }
```

There is also information here on how to completely disable the default pills in the .js https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/2777

And there is a similiar question here on Stack Overflow about custom indicators (using new CSS classes to replace the default Bootstrap ones): [twitter bootstrap custom carousel indicators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844157/twitter-bootstrap-custom-carousel-indicators)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer to my question, but a decent alternative.
I ended up using Jquery Cycle2 instead.

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" 
data-cycle-fx=scrollHorz
data-cycle-timeout=0
data-cycle-pager="#no-template-pager"
data-cycle-pager-template=""
data-cycle-slides="> div"
>
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/650x350/3f32fd/fff" width=650 height=350></div>
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/650x350/113f11/fff" width=650 height=350></div>
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/650x350/d3df3f/fff" width=650 height=350></div>
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/650x350/d32e11/fff" width=650 height=350></div>
</div>

<div id=no-template-pager class="cycle-pager external">
   <!-- using thumbnail image files would be even better! -->
<img src="http://placehold.it/80x80/3f32fd/fff" width=80 height=80>
<img src="http://placehold.it/80x80/113f11/fff" width=80 height=80> 
<img src="http://placehold.it/80x80/d3df3f/fff" width=80 height=80> 
<img src="http://placehold.it/80x80/d32e11/fff" width=80 height=80>
</div>
```

Here's a working jsfiddle example.

http://jsfiddle.net/6E5zq/

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom images by changing the following:

**To change the custom indicators**

```
 .carousel-indicators li{
    background: url(../images/imagename.png) no-repeat !important;
    width:35px !important;
    height:35px !important;
    cursor: pointer !important;
    text-align:center !important;
    border:none !important;
}
```

**To change the active indicator image**

```
.carousel-indicators li.active{
background: url(../images/imagenameactive.png) no-repeat !important;
}
```

Please note that for responsive design it is probably better practice to use either ems or % instead of px. You also may not need the !important tags; however, the way my styles were laid out it was a necessity.